# Time tracker program assistance

Tags: c++

I have to make a time tracking program. The goal is to have the user be prompted to enter the date, hours put in and description of task and then it will print them all in columns (haven't written column code yet), however I am getting many errors and I don't know the best way to go about this. I need to hours to total up at the end. here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int hours = 0;
string i;
int j = 0;
string h;
string date;
string task;
int totalHours;
char answer;
while(1) {

    cout << "Please enter the date of the task: ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Please enter the number of hours worked: ";
    cin >> j;
    cout << "Please enter the description of the task completed: "; 
    cin >> h;
    if(j != 0 && i != 0 && h != 0)
    {
        printf("Entry added. ");
        while(1){ 
            date = i;
            hours = j;
            task = h;
            totalHours = hours + j; }
    else {
        break; 
    }   }
cout << "Would you like to enter another task?(y or n): ";
cin >> answer;
if (answer == 'n'){
    cout << "Your time is spent like this" << date << " " << hours << " " << task; 
    cout << "The total number of hours spent is" << totalHours;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on the situation?

Comment: Didn't the compiler already shed some light on the errors?

Comment: Also I noticed I dont have a statement to print the columns which i need

Comment: @HAL i am unsure of these errors. I tried everything to "declare it in the scope"

Comment: are you sure you are compiling the file which contains the code you show (i.e., is the code you show the content of ' shuffle_string.cpp')? it seems compiler is complaining about "â" character, which is nowhere in the code you show

Comment: What are you trying to do with this for-loop:
            for(i > 0; j > 0; h > 0) {

Comment: yup that looks like a neverending loop. check your c++ tutorial again on what actually should go into the three parts of the for loop

Comment: Yeah my code needs some work

Comment: @nyarlathotep can anyone tell me why im getting not declared in scope errors?

Comment: @nyarlathotep thanks i read up but i know which ones arent declared but i declared them. Did i put them in the wrong spot?

Comment: "but i know which ones arent declared" - so, would you care to enlighten us, or do you want to leave us guessing which ones it is? it's very nice to have the compiler message - but those don't seem to be properly aligned to the code you show. see also my answer

Comment: @nyarlathotep check out my new code was mixing up c++ and C. fixed alot

Comment: so you removed the compiler errors. what is the problem now? please don't change the question that radically - if the original problem is solved and you got a new one, ask a new question. but first, do some research yourself!

Comment: @nyarlathotep My code SHOULD run however I am getting lines of compiler errors that say "a is not derived from a" on my if loop

Comment: please see my comment above on how to proceed. i will not take part in this prolonged discussion any longer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have some terminal encoding issues. The compiler actually prints something else than â. For how to solve, see here: https://superuser.com/questions/264089/strange-characters-in-terminal-during-compile-error
Quick summary: Try running your compiler with `LC_ALL=en_US` prefix, e.g.

```
 LC_ALL=en_US g++ shuffle_string.cpp
```

If the code you show is not exactly aligned as the code you compile (regarding line numbers), the compilation errors might come from a missing `std::` in front of the `string` types (it should be `std::string`) - the same goes for `cout` and `cin`.

Also, you should

```
#include <string>
```

not `string.h`